# WPF: Sum of Property of List in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a List of objects, each object in the list contains as a property a second list of objects. I would like to display the sum of a property in the second list in my ListView. This is what I currently have.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllLineItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLineItem}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LineItem}" Header="Line Item" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- I do not want to display a ComboBox I would like -->
                        <!-- to display the total of the Quantity property.   -->
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ShippingHistories}" DisplayMemberPath="Quantity" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **value converter**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            IEnumerable enumerable = value as IEnumerable;

            if (enumerable == null)
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            IEnumerable<object> collection = enumerable.Cast<object>();

            PropertyInfo property = null;
            string propertyName = parameter as string;
            if (propertyName != null && collection.Any())
            {
                property = collection.First().GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            }

            return collection.Select(x => System.Convert.ToInt32(property != null ? property.GetValue(x) : x)).Sum();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
...
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SumConverter x:Key="sumConverter"></local:SumConverter>
</Window.Resources>
...
<GridViewColumn Header="Quantity">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShippingHistories,Converter={StaticResource sumConverter},ConverterParameter=Quantity}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Not tested but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, I went down this road as well but couldn't find an example where they passed a parameter. I'll come back and mark this as the answer if I get it to work.

Comment: I think the `GetValue` method needs two arguments. I've changed your second argument to `null`, but refer to this for any semantic inconsistency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HugoSFerreira Not with WPF 4.5 which provides a new overload :)

Comment: @Pragmateek: you're absolutely correct, my apologies! I've reverted my change.

Comment: @HugoSFerreira No problem, this is a subtle change I've discovered myself by writing this code. Thanks for taking care of the technical accuracy of answers. :)